# Rails check if model is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created model Profile.rb
I have on the db column `name`, Currently it's empty
How do I check on the rails console if Profile is empty?
I have tried `Profile.empty?` but I guess that's not the right way

Comment: what does it mean `empty`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, try to find any Profile object:

```
Profile.first.nil?
```

Answer (score 15):

This also could be an Option for you.

```
Profile.any?
```

This will make a query to DB like

```
Profile.any?
# (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles"
# => false
```

This would be more semantic I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
Profile.exists?
```

it will return true if the table is not empty and false if the table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
Profile.first.present?
```

This makes the code more readable imho but `nil?` works too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you mean the Profile table is empty, or the name column in any one Profile entry is empty.

As mentioned by kjprice, you could just query the database for first. Or do

```
Profile.all.count < 1
```

Otherwise, I'd guess you were looking at the name column in a single Profile entry.

```
Profile.first.name.empty?
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking to check if the column name is empty, very useful

Comment: `Profile.all.count < 1` implicitly means `Profile.all.count == 0`, so let use `Profile.all.count.zero?`, it is clearer !